# Picture slideshow with swipe and page control

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I'm creating a "how-to"view where I show the user 5-6 pictures on how to use the app. I want it to be like a container inside the real view. Also I want it to have a transition with swipe and a page control. Something like the AppStore has on the pictures with screenshots of an app if you know what I mean?

Is there an easy way to do this? All help highly appreciated!

Comment: Charlu codes have so many missing... And somebody can say "Worked perfectly".. No comments, na values (PAGECONTROL_HEIGTH) like that, no definitions etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here a simple code, but you can customize it with loop, animation or what you want to do ;) ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //init scollview
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:myBounds];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    //Ajout des covers classiques
    for (int i = 0; i < [myCovers count]; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;

        //Vue 1
        UIView *subview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [subview1 addSubview:[myCovers objectAtIndex:i]];
        [scrollView addSubview:subview1];
    }

    //Content Size Scrollview
    scrollViewBack.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollViewBack.frame.size.width * ([myCovers count]), scrollViewBack.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollViewBack];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*([myCovers count]), scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    //Page Control
    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollView.frame.size.height - PAGECONTROL_HEIGTH - myBaseline, scrollView.frame.size.width, PAGECONTROL_HEIGTH)];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = [myCovers count];
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Params setting

- (void) setObjects:(NSArray *)covers {
    myCovers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:covers];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Scrollview delegate

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger offsetLooping = 1;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + offsetLooping;
    pageControl.currentPage = page % [myCovers count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create `UIImageView` for the 'n' number of images you have.
2. Add this images on `UIScrollView`. Keep the size of your scrollview same as your `UIImageView` size.
3. **Most important thing, enable the Paging property of UIScrollView**

It should give you the look same as AppStore screen
shot screen.